# Execution reverted when trying pair.getReserves()

Tags: tokens, ethers.js, nodejs, bsc, pancakeswap

Here is the code I've wrote:

[Swap Token Gist](https://gist.github.com/jlescalonap/d55fe86ed56a58688ea479259e5e5805)

Here's one of the TxId with the revert:

[BSC Scan Tx Id](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd38b7bf9a7912e4f2b61c9d9ddabd26376cb0a2452e347f68773358d80d98b00)

And here is a screenshot with the revert message:

[image: Reverted]

Why is the contract reverting if there are reserves, I've triple checked before directly on the pair contract?.

https://bscscan.com/address/0x2D9948C34F67435a7b092E45Ea399093e16223A9#writeContract

Comment: You're passing only 250k gas, is it what the wallet is estimating? Seems quite low

Comment: I hardcoded it but yes, I used an estimated, I've raised the value, still the same error:
 https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcb6dde0251011584f90d109e2d52eaf4366dfd3e4eb31cb078dd809f0e74e307

Comment: Nope, not the same error anymore: now it's reverting with INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT, as you're calling swapExactETH(...) without passing a msg.value

Comment: oh man, it was that, thanks now it works!, thank you, how do I close the question as answered?, I'm new around...

Comment: I added it as an answer that you might now accept;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're facing 2 issues:

- the transaction you mention revert without obvious reason, but you might notice the gas left at 0 (and the gas passed as 250k). This is really low (difficult to estimate as it will depend on the token implementation, but see this random swap consuming more than 1 million for instance https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc40e6ba9340e5b0de31034f6e318b408c3b8b5a89ec0c208959d72ab52378bdc)
- You use `swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` yet do not pass any value (ie use a msg.value reflecting the amount of eth or bnb you'd like to swap)

Comment: Thank you, it's solved now!